# http2.load is a dangling symlink

Tags: server, apache2, symbolic-link, php7

I have just upgraded my Google Compute Engine to Ubuntu 16.04 lts and now cannot get apache2 to restart!

I first ran `sudo apache2ctl configtest` and got this:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/http2.load: No such file or directory
```

I have checked both the mods-enabled and mods-available directories and http2.load is nowhere to be seen! I even `sudo a2enmod http2.load` but got told it is a symlink.

Naturally because of this I cannot start apache2. anyone have any ideas what my next play is! 
Please do excuse my ignorance if this is an easy fix, i am still quite a novice when it comes to building servers!

- Phillip Dews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by editing `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and commenting out or deleting the reference to http2.load on line 140.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

As why that file disappeared I don't know, at least you should be able to start apache from there.

Comment: Thanks @darent Got it all sorted now and posted another answer below!

Answer (score 1):

Got it all fixed now! for those of you that are interested this is what I did to fix it! first off I reinstalled apache

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

Then I added python software properties

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Next i re-installed apache

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install apache2 -y
```

and finally I Enabled the http2 module `sudo a2enmod http2`

And all is now well!